# Which continuous speech recognition service can I use for Xamarin.Android project?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx-android

I'm looking for a service that could record voice continuously for about 10 minutes (without any interruption). This service should be able to detect some keywords (mainly numbers).

I'm currently using Android.Speech.SpeechRecognizer. It works well but the record can only last for about 10 seconds. I tried to set some "ExtraSpeechInput" parameters as follow without success :

```
private Intent SpeechRecognizerIntent { get; set; }
//...
mySpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
mySpeechRecognizerIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 15000);
mySpeechRecognizerIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 15000);
mySpeechRecognizerIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 60000);
```

It seems that I am not the only one to have issues with this. 
So I tried to make a CMU PocketSphinx wrapper. Though all, I ended up with errors...

Does someone know which service I can use?